# Parse and Swift Xcode 6.3 issue

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

EDIT:  I'm thinking this error might be due to the fact that Xcode 6.3 may have changed some features around and the query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId was one of them....

I am trying to run a query but when I run the method "query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId" , I am getting the error message:

"Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type (string, block: (PFObject!,NSError?) -> Void"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let score = PFObject(className: "gameScore")




    var query = PFQuery(className: "gameScore")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("HK0UbuTIQL", block: {
        (score: PFObject!, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil  {

            println("pussiesPoundedCreated")

        } else {

            println(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the block statement and unwrap the variables like this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "gameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("HK0UbuTIQL") {
  (gameScore: PFObject!, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
    println(gameScore)
  } else {
    println(error)
  }
}
```

Parse.com documentation is pretty good and has Swift available for most all code examples.  [Here is a link to this topic](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS)

Comment: I used the code snippet you provided above, which is the same syntax as provided in the Parse.com documentation link.

I am STILL getting error "Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type (string, (PFObject!,NSError?) -> Void)"

    var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("j4I4z0z0Yh") {
            (gameScore: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
                println(gameScore)
            } else }
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Try changing `NSError!` to `NSError?` and check your `className` capitalization.  I think your close. Also, I noticed your Id changed so check to make sure you have that correct.

Comment: Unfortunately this was unable to solve the issue too.  I'm thinking Xcode 6.3 added a couple new features and slightly changed the syntax of this method.

Answer (score 0):

This method takes a block with the argument signature `(PFObject!, NSError!)`, but the block you wrote has an argument signature of `(PFObject!, NSError?)`. Change `NSError?` to `NSError!`.

You should also use the [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) in [Portland Runner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777050/1445366) because it's more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Aaron.  I have made the changes you recommended and am still seeing the same error!